# Not able to show a BottomSheetDialogFragment from adapter in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, bottom-sheet

The bottomsheet fragment consists of a recyclerview and it is always opened when i start the app

This is the button from which i am starting the fragment, if any other info is required i am happy to provide thank you.

```
      public profiles_adapter(Context context, int resourceId, ArrayList<profiles> profiles) {
    super(context, resourceId, profiles);
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    profiles profile = getItem(position);
    //image stuff
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cards, parent, false);
    }
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager userImageViewPager;
    userImageViewPager = convertView.findViewById(R.id.userImageViewPager);

    String[] imageUrls = new String[]{};
    if (profile.getImages() != null) {
        imageUrls = profile.getImages();
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(context, imageUrls);
        userImageViewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    }



    more_info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle data = new Bundle();//create bundle instance
            data.putString("profile_id", profile.getProfile_id());//put string to pass with a key value
            user_details ud = new user_details();
            ud.setArguments(data);//Set bundle data to fragment
            ud.show( ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager(),"tagg");

        }
    });
```

Comment: user_details is a fragment?

Comment: yes it is BottomSheetDialogFragment

Comment: and more_info.setOnClickListener is inside your recyclerview adapter ?

Comment: yes it is present in my adapter

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your activity not the `context`, so the BottomSheet will be shown.
Or I suggest building an interface so the adapter can communicate with (Activity/Fragment).

```
private ClickListener clickListener;
 public profiles_adapter(Context context, int resourceId, ArrayList<profiles> profiles,ClickListener clickListener) {
    super(context, resourceId, profiles);
    this.context = context;
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}

public interface ClickListener{
    void onClickMoreInfo(String profileId);
}
```

now on your click listener :

```
 more_info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       clickListener.onClickMoreInfo(profile.getProfile_id());
         }
    });
```

And let assume you have like this on your (Activity/Fragment)

```
profiles_adapter adapter = new profiles_adapter(context,id,list,this);
```

now make your (Activity/Fragment) implement your interface

`implements ClickListener`

and finally

```
@Override
public void onClickMoreInfo(String profileId){
    Bundle data = new Bundle();//create bundle instance
    data.putString("profile_id", profile.getProfile_id());//put string to pass with a key value
    user_details ud = new user_details();
    ud.setArguments(data);//Set bundle data to fragment
 /*for activity*/   ud.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"tagg");
  /*for fragment*/  ud.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"tagg");
}
```

Comment: i am not able to understand can you do that change in code and paste in answer

Comment: added in questin please check

Comment: let me check it